# how do I get the argument "someelement" to imageLoaded?

Tags: javascript, arguments, addeventlistener

How do I get the argument "someDiv" to imageLoaded?

My confusion is caused by the fact that imageLoaded is called by the event and already passes its own argument (that is captured by the argument "someImg")

```
window.onload = function()
{
    imageLoader(someURL, someDiv);

    function imageLoader(someURL, someDiv)
    {
        var someImg = document.createElement("img");

        someImg.addEventListener("load", imageLoaded, false); // <- line x
        someImg.src = someURL;
    }
}

function imageLoaded(someImg, someDiv)
{
    // assuming that someDiv has a background image, set the size of
    // the div to the size of the background image

    someDiv.style.width = someImg.target.width;
    someDiv.style.height = someImg.target.height;

    someImg.removeEventListener("load", imageLoaded, false);
}
```

I can change line x to

```
someImg.addEventListener("load", function(){imageLoaded(someImg, someDiv);}, false);
```

but then I can not remove the eventListener, because I don't have a proper function reference

Another question is that the onload event fires at the end of the document loading process, when all images have finished loading. How can it be that the event still fires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create a named function to handle the event
function loadedHandler() {
    // Now you can pass the params to your imageLoaded function
    imageLoaded(someImg, someDiv);
}

someImg.addEventListener("load", loadedHandler, false);
// And remove the listener
someImg.removeEventListener("load", loadedHandler);
```

You could also use the `target` property of the event object to remove the listener.

```
// Create a named function to handle the event
function loadedHandler(event) {
    event.target.removeEventListener('load', loadedHandler);
}
```

The event fires because you're creating a new element within `onLoad` and listening for the `load` event on it. Although the image in the `someURL` parameter may have been loaded with the rest of the document (it's not clear from your question whether or not that's the case) it needs to be loaded (or loaded again) for the new element you've created.

Comment: say, I don't remove it, will it be removed automatically because someImg is a local variable? Or will the variable and the eventlistener keep referencing each other forever?

Comment: I'll be honest and say that I'm not 100% sure. However, I think the issue is that the event listener is attached to a DOM element, which just happens to be stored on a local variable in your case - so I think as long as the DOM element persists, the listener will too. Regardless, it's a good practice always to clear up your listeners. Another angle you could look at, if your handler doesn't have the scope of the variable the listener was attached to is to use the event target.